# PHP function print data from array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to write a php function that would print the data in the below array as an HTML unordered list, containing hyperlinks with the 'title' item as the linked copy, the 'path' item as the link's href, and the items in the 'class' array as classes for those links.

```
$mymenu = array(
   0 => array(
      'path' => 'all',
      'title' => 'All Content',
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('first-item', 'menu-item'),
        ),
      ),
   1 => array(
      'path' => 'videos',
      'title' => 'Videos',
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('item', 'menu-item'),
        ),
      ),
   2 => array(
      'path' => 'articles',
      'title' => 'Articles',
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('last-item', 'menu-item'),
        ),
      ),
);
```

Here's what I have, I'm having trouble with the attributes I think:

```
foreach($mymenu as $item) {
echo '<a href=' . $item['path'] . 'class="' . $item['attributes'] . '" />' . $item['title'] . '</a> <br>';

}
```

Comment: what you have tried  ?

Comment: It's just a `foreach` loop with an `echo` statement in it. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: just try something yourself and then post here

Comment: I'm having a problem with the class attribute part, adding 'first-item' class for the first item and 'last-item' class for the last item. Otherwise, the foreach loops works well.

Comment: update your question with foreach loop

Comment: @Air, if you need classes for css only you could use pseudo class of css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seemed to do the trick:

```
foreach($mymenu as $item) {
echo '<a href="'.$item['path'].'"class="'.$item['attributes']['class'][0] . ' ' .$item['attributes']['class'][1].'" />' . $item['title'] . '</a> <br>';  
}
```